# Retrieving tweets from since the start of the month with tweepy

Tags: python, datetime, twitter, tweepy

I'm trying to retrieve tweets from the start of the current month using Tweepy. Here is how I defined the dates:

```
now = datetime.now()
monthstart = now.replace (day = 1)
```

and how I try to retrieve tweets:

```
#test print
a = [] #raw
b = [] #preprocessed
c = [] #place
d = [] #coord
for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search,q="#lalinbdg", tweet_mode = 'extended',
                           since=monthstart).items():
                           a.append(tweet.full_text)
                           b.append(tweet.full_text)
                           c.append(tweet.place)
                           d.append(tweet.coordinates)
                           b = list(dict.fromkeys(b)) #remove duplicates
                           for text in b:
                             text = text.casefold() #lowercase
                             print(text)
```

When I try to specify the date with the monthstart variable it won't return any output.
It seems like the 'since'  only accepts date strings since it works when I use one like '2020-07-01', does anyone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `since` parameter needs to be a string, and you are passing a datetime object. So you need to convert it to a string using [`strftime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior). Note that `datetime.now()` has a time component, so you would be better using [`date.today()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.today) otherwise you might miss some entries from times on the 1st of the month which are earlier than the time now. In all:

```
today = date.today()
monthstart = today.replace(day=1).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```